# How to update Controls on specific event by using telerik:RadAjaxManager

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I'm new to telerik controls.

I'm using following code to Update my controls asyncronously.

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID =  "RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">

    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting EventName="OnSelectedIndexChanged" AjaxControlID="grd_optnandprcng">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Req_items"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>                    
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

as my code shows, i just want to update control **Req_items** (rad gridview) only on **OnSelectedIndexChanged** event of **grd_optnandprcng** (rad gridview).

But its not working. Its updating control on every event of radgridview.

Anyone have any idea to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you surely can achieve this. Try this:

1. Call javascript on the SelectedIndexChanged event:

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="grd_optnandprcng" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="myGrid_SelectedIndexChanged">
   ```
2. From javascript, make an ajax request using the RadAjaxManager:

   ```
   function myGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(){
       $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("RefreshReqItems");
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget to modify your RadAjaxManager:

   ```
   <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" 
              DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"
              OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest">
      <AjaxSettings>
          <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager1">
                 <UpdatedControls>
                      <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Req_items">
                      </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>                    
                </UpdatedControls>
          </telerik:AjaxSetting>
      </AjaxSettings>
   </telerik:RadAjaxManager> >
   ```
4. Do whatever you need to do to refresh your items:

   ```
   protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Argument.Equals("RefreshReqItems"))
       {
           //Refresh something or rebind something else.
       }
   }
   ```